# how to send message from one user to another inside ejabberd module

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to send message from one user to another. I don't want to send message from client and for that i am using mod_rest for catching HTTP requests, but i can't properly route message stanza from one user to another.

I tried to call `mod_mam:user_send_packet`, but message haven't saved in archive for reciever.

Is there any clean way to solve these problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [**ejabberd_router:route/1**](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/src/ejabberd_router.erl#L91).
For knowing more about its possible argument you should read `iq`, `message` and `presence` records of [**xmpp_codec.hrl**](https://github.com/processone/xmpp/blob/1.1.19/include/xmpp_codec.hrl).
For c2s chat `ejabberd_router` uses `ejabberd_sm` module to sending packet. `ejabberd_sm` adds `offline_message_hook` and  [**here**](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/src/ejabberd_sm.erl#L755) it runs this hook. In [**here**](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/src/mod_offline.erl#L112) module `mod_offline` uses `offline_message_hook`. So when receiver is offline and `mod_offline` is active, message will store.

Comment: i tried route function but, message wasn't stored in archive...also i want to activate carbon-copy on that message

Comment: did you use mod_offline? Can you create a github gist with some code snippet?

Comment: It seems that code is right. Include Ejabberd "logger.hrl" header and insert `?INFO_MSG("log about ~p", [Something])` in different clauses of code, then recompile the code and see Ejabberd log file. You will figure out what clause does not match.

Comment: everything is fine expect that message for sender is not saved in archive... and there is no error in log file.. i am listening to log file with tailf ejabberd.log | grep error. 

maybe it's problem with hooks priority
  

ejabberd_hooks:add(user_send_packet, Host, ?MODULE, on_user_send_packet, 50),
  ejabberd_hooks:add(user_receive_packet, Host, ?MODULE, on_user_receive_packet, 50),

Comment: Did you try with priority 1? carbon_copy uses priority 89, mod_privacy uses 50, mod_mam uses 88, mod_ping uses 100, mod_privilege uses 50.

Comment: i tried hooks priority with 1 and 600 but still the same...there is no message record for sender user in archive

Comment: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/5054a9933f29d6cc8a88486c624987b1b9f05b17/src/mod_mam.erl#L301 ejabebrd_router:route/1 actually doesn't initiate send_packet_hook for sender :/ i have inserted ?INFO_MSG on that line, but log showed only messages sent by clients

Comment: If you want to archive message for offline user, you need mod_offline and this line https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/src/ejabberd_sm.erl#L739 should be executed.
You can run ejabberdctl set_loglevel 5 and find these logs https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/src/ejabberd_sm.erl lines 667 and 670. Its make you sure about routing message. (Iines are for ejabberd 18.01)

Comment: it doesn't matter if reciever is in offline or online. record for that user is correctly added to archive. problem is with sender.. ejabberd_router:route/1 doesn't initiate mod_mam:user_send_packet hook and this is the reason why record for sender is not added in archive

Comment: Try with running that hook like https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/src/ejabberd_c2s.erl#L465

Comment: it worked! but know reciever didn't get message. should i use ejabberd_route:route/1 and  ejabberd_hooks:run_fold(user_send_packet, LServer, {Pkt1, C2SState}, []) together?

Comment: Yes, first run hook, then use ejabberd_router:route/1